# Forward incoming messages from Telegram to another chat

Tags: python, telegram

I am trying to make all the messages I receive from a chat (Chat A) automatically forward to another chat (Chat B). I am not the admin of Chat A. I've been looking into this for a while, but I don't see how its possible to do with Telegram Bot, correct me if I'm wrong. Basically I need a way to read in all incoming messages on my Telegram account.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: i am using python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. When a new message is either received or sent `my_event_handler` is called automatically.

`if '1113462530' in str(event):` this line basically is looking if the message came from a specific chat `1113462530` (this is the chat id), and if it did a message is sent to `PERSON_NAME`.

```
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = 1234
api_hash = 'abc123'

client  = TelegramClient('session_id', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if '1113462530' in str(event):
        await client.send_message('PERSON_NAME', event.raw_text)

client.run_until_disconnected()
```